# Python function on the command line not working

Tags: python, command-line

Consider this simple python:

```
def cube(x): 
   return x*x*x;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(cube(4));
```

Works ok. But when I open up the python command line interpreter and do:

```
>>> def cube(x): return x*x*x;
... cube(4);
```

I get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    cube(4);
     ^
SyntaxEror: invalid syntax
```

What stupid thing are my doing wrong?

Comment: No need of semi-colons in python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try pressing enter one more time :) The ellipse in front of your `cube(4)` indicates that you are still defining your function. Also, you can remove the semicolon:

```
>>> def cube(x): return x*x*x
...
>>> cube(4)
64
```

Comment: This is so embarrasing - should I delete the question?

Comment: @dublintech Ha, I'd be lying if I said it hadn't happened to me before :) Not embarrassing at all.

Comment: @dublintech Also, no need to delete the question. Hopefully someone learns something from it, possibly in a year when encountering the same problem. Let's say you contributed to documenting Python :)

Comment: @dublintech: Consider that you have upvotes on your question. Then consider how many more python beginners will benefit from google showing them this post.